# apply a class to every other element in react map data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have the below:

```
    <div className="grid md:grid-cols-2 sm:grid-cols-2 grid-cols-1 gap-16 mt-24 px-4">
      {status === "success" &&
        delve(data, "restaurants") &&
        data.restaurants.map((restaurant, index) => (
        <div className=""> <---------------- i.e.
          <RestaurantCard
            {...restaurant.attributes}
            locale={locale}
            key={index}
          />
        </div>
        ))}
    </div>
```

I want to apply a class to every other element within my `.map` function. Reason is, as opposed to standard side by side grid column, I am creating a checkerboard type layout, so every other item I will need to margin up higher. How could I apply such a style to only other item in `data.restaurants.map((restaurant, index) => (` ?

Comment: `.map()` passes your function the index, so you could check even/odd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply conditional `className` according to your index.

For example,

```js
    <div className="grid md:grid-cols-2 sm:grid-cols-2 grid-cols-1 gap-16 mt-24 px-4">
      {status === "success" &&
        delve(data, "restaurants") &&
        data.restaurants.map((restaurant, index) => (
        <div className={"" + (index % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even')}> <---------------- i.e.
          <RestaurantCard
            {...restaurant.attributes}
            locale={locale}
            key={index}
          />
        </div>
        ))}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If is the same style, add your class in the `div` inside of the `map`

```
        <div className="YOURCLASS"> <---------------- i.e.
```

Also if you need to make some logic to apply the class

```
        <div className={variable === 'something' ? CLASS1 : CLASS2}> <---------------- i.e.
```

Also you can apply the class to your component

```
<RestaurantCard
 {...restaurant.attributes}
 locale={locale}
 key={index}
 style={styles...}
/>
```

And then apply that style in the component file

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modulus operator (%) to check if the index is even or odd. Based on that, you can conditionally apply different classes to alternate elements, creating a pattern or checker switching logic.

Based on your example:

```
<div className="grid md:grid-cols-2 sm:grid-cols-2 grid-cols-1 gap-16 mt-24 px-4">
  {status === "success" &&
    delve(data, "restaurants") &&
    data.restaurants.map((restaurant, index) => (
      <div className={index % 2 === 0 ? "even-item" : "odd-item"}>
        <RestaurantCard {...restaurant.attributes} locale={locale} key={index} />
      </div>
    ))}
</div>
```